# Datatables: I get 'cannot read property of undefined data' when table is responsive

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a datatables, which is filled with json data from the db.
[image]

As you can see in the last column, there are 2 buttons, one for updating and the other one for deleting the data.
When pressing the button, the value of NumEmpleado(hidden), Nombre, email and Password passes to a form.

[image]

It works just fine, buf if I resize my browser enough to kick in the responsiveness layout. Then when I click on the blue button(update), the console says it cannot read the property. I can imagine is because of the responsive layout, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.

[image: Here I clicked on blue button to load the info on the update form]

This is table code:

```
    <div class="table-responsive col-sm-12">
        <table id="dt_cliente" class="table table-bordered table-hover nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NumEmpleado</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>TipoCuenta</th>
                    <th>Operaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is how the table is populated and then adds the update/delete buttons

```
var listar = function(){
                $("#cuadro2").slideUp("slow");
                $("#cuadro1").slideDown("slow");
            var table = $("#dt_cliente").DataTable({
                "destroy":true,
                "responsive": true,
                "ajax":{
                    "method":"POST",
                    "url": "listar.php"
                    },
                    "columns":[
                        {"data": "NumEmpleado"},
                        {"data": "nombre"},
                        {"data": "correo"},
                        {"data": "tipoCuenta"},
                        {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='editar btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></button> <button type='button' class='eliminar btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEliminar' ><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>"}
                        ],
                        "language": idioma_espanol,
                        "dom": "Bfrtip",
                        "buttons": [
                            {
                                "text": "<i class='fa fa-refresh'></i>",
                                "titleAttr": "Recargar Datos",
                            //  "className": "btn btn-sucess",
                                "action": function(){
                                    listar();
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                text:   '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                                titleAttr: 'Excel'
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                                text:   '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>',
                                titleAttr: 'CSV'
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                text:   '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                                titleAttr: 'PDF'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                obtener_data_editar("#dt_cliente tbody", table);
            }
```

and this is the function that get the values from the table to place them on a form. (blue update button)

```
        var obtener_data_editar = function(tbody, table) {
            $(tbody).on("click", "button.editar", function(){
                var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
                var numEmpleado = $("#numEmpleado").val( data.NumEmpleado),
                    nombre = $("#nombre").val( data.nombre ),
                    correo = $("#correo").val(data.correo),
                    password = $("#password").val(data.password),
                    opcion = $("#opcion").val("modificar");

                    $("#cuadro2").slideDown("slow");
                    $("#cuadro1").slideUp("slow");
            });
        }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's making it responsive? Inspect your html structure before and after the break points, are more `<tr>`s being added to the `<table>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in either of these:-

1)Listener

2)Destroy

3)It is not able find the value of that variable because of some issues.

Kindly check all these and tell me if it solves the issue